# MongoDB C# cursor performance issue

Tags: performance, mongodb, cursor, mongodb-.net-driver

I installed the lastest MongoDB 64 bit DB and official C# driver as of 13 Marh 2012. I am getting some unexpected performace results with cursors.

The following code will retrieve and loop through 500,000 records at about 26.8 k / sec on my Core 2 Duo 2 GHz laptop:

```
    var query = Query.EQ("_H._t", "Car");
    var cursor = mc.FindAs<RoctObj>(query);
    double priceTot = 0d;

    foreach (RoctObj item in cursor)
    {
        Car car = (Car)item._H;
        priceTot += car.Price;
    }
```

That seems reasonable. Next, I adjusted the query so that only 721 results are returned. The code takes over 1.1 seconds longer to execute than if the foreach segment is replaced with:

```
    long i = cursor.Count();
```

Given the speed of the first example, 721 records should only take a fraction of a second to iterate. I know there are some other overheads, but they should be that bad. I don't understand why I am getting +1.1 seconds.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is the alternate query. Note that the query time isn't the question. It's the iteration time.

```
    var query = Query.And(
        Query.LTE("_H.Price", BsonDouble.Create(80000d)).GTE(BsonDouble.Create(40000d)),
        Query.LTE("_H.Cylinders", BsonDouble.Create(8d)).GTE(BsonDouble.Create(4d)),
        Query.LTE("_H.Capacity", BsonDouble.Create(3000d)).GTE(BsonDouble.Create(2000d)),
        Query.LTE("_H.TopSpeed", BsonDouble.Create(200d)).GTE(BsonDouble.Create(100d))
        );
```

Comment: How did you adjust the query? Did you just use a `limit`? You should use the `explain()` feature to get a better idea of the two query plans, and maybe add that to your question.

Comment: I showed the adjusted query in the edit. Although the length of execution of the query isn't the issue, how do I use explain from within C#?

Comment: Rather than doing explain using the C# driver, use the shell or better yet a GUI like MongoVUE which is great.  And are you sure its not an issue of query time?  How are you sure?  MongoDB does not return all the results at once, it returns a cursor which reads data off the database one record at a time, as your application asks for it (i.e. during your iterations)

Comment: Well, if I ask for the count of the recordset, I get the correct answer (I verified via shell). But if I loop through, it takes +1.1 secs for the 700 odd. I don't see how it could have "not done" the query if it gives me the count. So I am pretty sure the extra time is in fact the iteration.

Comment: Ps. Kaspersky reports the MongoVUE website as containing a trojan :(

Comment: I think you answered the question. Although Mongo knows there are 700 odd records because of the index, and hence can give me the answer, it hasn't yet had to walk through them. They are scattered. However, the 500,000 is literally every second record, which means it's a 50% efficient sequential read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not return all the results at once, it returns a cursor which reads data off the database one record at a time, as your application asks for it (i.e. during your iterations) which may be why it is slower.

Running a `count()` simply returns the amount of matches found but without data.

Answer (score 3):

Calling cursor.Count() transfers no data from the server to your application. It sends a command to the server and the count is performed on the server, and only a tiny packet comes back from the server containing the numeric result of the count.

Not sure why iterating over the documents is taking that much longer than a simple count. One reason could be that the server is able to compute the count using only an index, but that when you actually iterate over the documents the server would have to fetch every single document from disk if it was not already paged into memory.

It is unlikely to be any bottleneck in the C# driver deserialization code as that is quite fast.

If you can provide a sample program that demonstrates the observed behavior I would be happy to try and reproduce your results.

Comment: I ran the same test, but with 10% of the DB size, and the results were > 30 times faster, which confirms MDB was having to go to disk.

Comment: Thanks @Robert. In the end, I had concluded the same thing you say here. Although Mongo knows there are 700 odd records because of the index, and hence can give me the answer, it hasn't yet had to walk through them. They are scattered. However, the 500,000 is literally every second record, which means it's a 50% efficient sequential read.